# Remove focus from ActionBar android Accessibility

Tags: android, accessibility

I've run into a few issues while implementing accessibility for my application. The focus always goes to the action bar which has the application title. I want the first focus to go to the header beneath the action bar and read the current screen title. I couldnt figure out how to disable the action bar focus. For my header textview I have set android:focusable="true"
and android:focusableInTouchMode="true" and I'm also requesting focus programatically. But it does not become the first element to get the focus. Please guide me on how to proceed.

Comment: I have a similar problem where the actionbar seems to steal focus from an EditText I have within a row in a listview.

Comment: This is not supported and I would recommend against trying to prevent the action bar from receiving accessibility focus. Accessibility focus always follows screen order and can be placed on all informative content, e.g. the action bar.

Comment: @alanv I have a scenario where i move from Activity A to Activity B, when some error occurs in B, I move back to A where I display an error message dynamically in a textview below a few edittext's. I want the user to be intimated of the error first, so that he enters the proper value in the edittext beneath it, instead of re-reading the complete screen again.